# net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH when trying to load javascript file from mobile

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile

I was trying to access a localhost site with a mobile device, managed to get it to work but I noticed that all of the javascript files were missing. Using the Chrome emulator, I got an error in the console:

> GET [path_to_mobile_functions]/mobile_functions.js?3 net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

A couple of observations:
a) When I try to use a browser with the failed GET request's URL - I actually see the JS code.
b) The same error happens on my staging server that I set up with Amazon (everything works except mobile).
c) On the live version - everything loads normally.

I'm guessing its some sort of setup problem with my local and staging server.
BTW the local system is Windows, and on the staging server I granted full permissions to apache on the project folders, so I don't think it's a permission issue.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: ever solve this problem?

Comment: I did, don't remember how (it was a while ago). Check out the php logs for errors, I think that's what guided me towards a solution.
Now that I think about it - it might have something to do with compression.
Try this:
http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4577/neterr-content-length-mismatch-for-cp-after-enabling-compression